# symfony2 - generate url across bundles

Tags: url, symfony, routes

I have a project that consists of multiple bundles and I would like to create links going to all sections.

```
indexAction()
{
  $UrlOne  = $this->generateUrl('stop_sell_homepage');
  $UrlTwo  = $this->generateUrl('pricewatch_homepage');
}
```

However the routing only finds the default links to its own bundle and I cannot seem to get it to cross over bundles?

Comment: The routing is global. Routes are compiled from every bundles and shared to all. You can't have two routes with the same key or they will be overwritten. Best option is to prefix the route key with bundle name